# firefox changes the extension of downloaded exe files with curl to html

Tags: php, firefox, curl

I implemented a php function that downloads some (.exe) files using curl extension. The file gets successfully downloaded but only in Firefox, their extension is "file.exe.html". Here is my function :

```
$source = isset($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] : ''; #get the download link
$filename = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'download.exe'; # define name
if($source != '')
{
        $handle = curl_init($source);
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        /* Check for 403 (forbidden). */
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($httpCode == 403) {
            echo "<h2> <font color='red'> Sorry you are not allowed to download that file.</font><h2>";
        } else {
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
            #header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"uploaded.pdf\"");
            // Get a FILE url to my test document

            $url= str_replace(" ","%20", $source);
            $ch= curl_init($url);
            #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5'); ## just tried it
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch); 
         }
        curl_close($handle);
}
else {
     echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to define the type of file, add
header('Content-Type: application/x-ms-application');